# doctrine2 zend framework namespaceing controllers

Tags: zend-framework, namespaces, controllers, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to integrate the doctrine2 sandbox with a default Zend Framework App. When I try to use namespacing in the controller I get an 'Invalid controller class ("IndexController")' error

This Works:

```
use Entities\User, Entities\Address;


class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
...
}
```

This does not (but should?):

```
namespace Entities;


class IndexController extends \Zend_Controller_Action
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you are importing namespaces into the controller. In your second example, you are assigning the controller to a namespace.

Importing a namespaces allows you to reference classes without having to user their fully qualified class name.

```
new \Entities\User() // without import
new User() // with import
```

Assigning a namespace to your controller actually changes the fully-qualified name for your class.

```
new \IndexController() // without namespace
new \Entities\IndexController() // with namespace
```

(Classes inside a namespace can always reference other classes in that same namespace without having to 'use' it. I suspect that was the primary reason you were trying to use option 2).

Zend Framework 1.10 is still namespace ignorant. When parsing a URL and trying to load a controller, it will look only look in the default global namespace for `\IndexController`, and have no idea that it's been assigned to a user defined namespace (`\Entities\IndexController`).

My recommendation is that when working with controllers in ZF, don't assign namespaces to them. Importing works fine. We'll have to wait until ZF 2.0 for full namespace support.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. What I don't understand is why placing a leading backwards slash in front of the controller name produces a syntax error. Both \IndexController and \Entities\IndexController produce the following error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR, expecting T_STRING

Comment: At any rate I will take your advice and just import namespaces for now.

Comment: I would add that Zend Framework isn't _completely_ namespace ignorant. It is simply that MVC controllers currently can't be namespaced. The rest of your library code, helpers, forms, etc. can be namespaced.

Answer (score 0):

After going thru [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) and reading some of [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/08/13/are-php-namespaces-bad/) it would seem that in PHP when you want to declare and construct around a namespace you use your second syntax. So that would create objects like

```
Entities\IndexController
```

so its not found anymore by Zend.

According to those site you have to use use to import a namespace and use it.

Thats why it works in your first example and not in your second one.

Hope I am right and this helps!

Comment: Entities\IndexController returns the following error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR, expecting '{'

I thought along similar lines and tried \IndexController earlier - but I got the same error

Comment: But why do you want to use the second version^ it doesnt work like that.If you want to import classes you type use myobject. So you want to use something in your controller is that it?